# LDAP config on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, ldap, openldap

I am trying to install openldap on Amazon Linux and got the following error:

```
olcRootPW: value #0: <olcRootPW> can only be set when rootdn is under suffix
config error processing olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config: <olcRootPW> can only be set when rootdn is under suffix
slaptest: bad configuration file!
```

I also tried putting the olcRootPW in the olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif file, but that just gives the same error. Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is quite clear. You can only set a password on the monitor database if the rootDN is under the suffix of the database. In other words the rootDN has to end with 'cn=monitor,cn=config'.

Answer (score 0):

Try the to add it like below, in the file `olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif`

```
olcSuffix: dc=my-domain,dc=com

olcRootDN: cn=manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com

olcRootPW: {SSHA}---password---
```